# K-Means with equal numbers of a binary attribute value in each cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

Given a certain binary attribute, I want to ensure that the clusters produced by K-means have equal numbers of data points where the said binary attribute's value is 1.

I know the above sentence is wordy so I will explain using an example.

Suppose I have an attribute "Asian" with 40 out of my 100 data points having the value of "Asian" = 1. For k = 10, I want each cluster to have exactly 4 points with "Asian" = 1.

Is there a simple way of achieving this? I have racked my brains but have not been able to come up with one. Please note that I am a beginner when it comes to clustering problems.

Comment: How about this: let `P` be any point that fits your value criteria. If a centroid gathers more than `n` `P`s; start moving `P`s from their current cluster to the best matching cluster (as defined by the distance between the point and the cluster's centroid) that has less than `n` `P`s?

Comment: It certainly is not k-means anymore... k-means does not make much sense on binary attributes anyway.

Comment: @Michael That sounds interesting. However, would that not make the clusters very spatially in-cohesive?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse It is a modification of k-means. Please keep in mind that other non-binary attributes are still present. The constraint applies only to a binary attribute.

Comment: @Rabee: I haven't tried that myself, so I don't know if it produces useful results. It was just an idea, hence making it a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, Michael. I see some issues with that approach but I will keep it in mind and it is certainly an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to perform such a k-means modification:

http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/SameSizeKMeans

It's not exactly what you need, but a closer k-means variant that can be easily adapted to your needs. Plus, it is a walkthrough tutorial.